# How to access secured backend API using API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I have created a backend spring-boot REST api which is deployed on the EC2 that is authenticated with JWT. So, I first curl to get the Bearer token:

```
curl -iH "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"myusername", "password":"mypassword"}' http://123.45.6782.910:8080/login
```

Then make the REST call to access my REST resource

```
curl -H "Authorization: eyJhbGzd9.NYHXPv-vXUIoNr7qtA" http://123.45.6782.910:8080/categories/pets/
```

This all works fine.

Now, I want to use API Gateway to access the `/categories/pets/` Resource.

I have setup GET - Method execution's Method request, Integration Request sections. But, when I try to Test the setup, I get 403.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1498392625274,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/categories/pets/"
}
```

I think this is expected because I am directly trying to access the backend api without the bearer token. I want to know how can I do the POST on `http://123.45.6782.910:8080/login` to get the Bearer token and then make the call to `/categories/pets/` ?

UPDATE: As per @KaHouIeong suggestion, I created a POST endpoint /login on the API gateway to get the bearer token, When I test is in the test console in the API Gateway, I am getting the `Authorization →Bearer eyJhbGzd9` but when I try it from postman, I am getting the status 200 OK but not the `Authorization →Bearer eyJhbGzd9` token.

```
content-length →0
content-type →application/json
status →200
via →1.1 swfbfbbaf3fb6c32bdccb152354539e473d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id →K9V3XUxHOretrza0kCM5dk_G5eZgePrtrBziyVTxptrePD7wjsWqk-l0kCQQ==
x-amzn-requestid →5ac81024-5c27-11e7-af9a-9f3c8494c542
x-amzn-trace-id →Root=1-5953e77f-ed76d15b5bfre9374c9
```

Comment: If you use Authorization bearer token, the header seems not correct, try this:
`-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGzd9.NYHXPv-vXUIoNr7qtA"`

Comment: No, that's not an issue here. You don't necessarily need bearer keyword. It's working for me without it.

Comment: Do you have any server log to take a look?

Comment: As I said before, this is not the issue. The issue is when I am making the call through API gateway, I don't know how to make the /login POST request so that I get the bearer token. If you read my question again hopefully it will be clearer.

Comment: Your client should send a request to ```/login``` and get the bearer token from the response, then re-use the token to access your ```/categories/pets/``` API. The workflow should be same as you hit your EC2 backend directly. For your API setup on API Gateway, you need to setup a ```/login``` resource and point to the ```http://123.45.6782.910:8080/login```

Comment: Thanks @KaHouIeong for this. I created a /login POST endpoint in the api gateway, I am getting 200 OK response, and other status but I am not getting `Authorization →Bearer eyJhbGzd...`

Comment: You need to setup the integration response header mapping to map the ```Authorization``` back to the method response, then API Gateway will pass through the header to the client.

Comment: Thanks, @KaHouIeong I did not set the Header mapping in the Integration Response. Mapping Authorization to integration.response.header.Authorization solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client should send a request to `/login` and get the bearer token from the response, then re-use the token to access your `/categories/pets/` API. 
The workflow should be same as you hit your EC2 backend directly.

For your API setup on API Gateway, you need to setup a `/login` resource and point to the `http://123.45.6782.910:8080/login`

Then, you need to setup the integration response header mapping to map the `Authorization` header back to the method response, then API Gateway will pass through the header to the client.

```
integration.response.header.Authorization -> method.response.header.Authorization
```